# Java SWT windowbuilder - images not displayed when exported to runnable jar

Tags: java, swt

I have developed a Java application using window builder(SWT) in eclipse. I have mapped images for logo and other labels. when i export them in Java 12 version as runnable jar, the images are displayed properly. But images not displayed when i generate jar with javaSE 1.8 version. i need the jar to be run on JavaSE1.8 version. help to resolve this

using WindowBuilder - 1.9.3

Code:

```
Display display = Display.getDefault();'
Shell shlMainWindow= new Shell();
shlMainWindow.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(MainWindow.class, "/org/eclipse/wb/swt/icon-software-service.png"));
shlMainWindow.setSize(631, 443);
shlMainWindow.setText("Main");
shlMainWindow.setLayout(new FormLayout());
```

Comment: SWT is **not** _Swing_

Comment: @Abra is there any solution for my issue?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with SWT. I looked at the _javadoc_ for method `getImage()` in class `SWTResourceManager`. The path must be relative to file `MainWindow.class`. Where is file `MainWindow.class`? Is it in a JAR file? Where is file `icon-software-service.png` located? Did you check whether method `getImage()` returns a value? Are you getting an exception? If so, [edit] your question and post a stack trace. Add calls to `System.out.println()` in your code so that when you run it, it displays what it is doing.